# Manipulating checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="news" value="right" id="right">Show News on the right
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="news" value="left" id="left">Show News on the left
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="color" name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">Set background color
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="green" id="green">Show green colors
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="red" id="red">Show red colors
    </label>    
</form>
<br>
<button>Customize!</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#green').prop('checked') == true) {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

Hey, how do I manipulate the checkbox, so that it would turn the background color of the body to green when "green" is checked, do the same thing with red color and when both are checked the green is chosen as a background. Also, is it possible to mark the checkbox and apply changes only when the "customize" button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.on()` to add events to all `input[type=checkbox]`, then check if green checked? if yes set body to green, if not check if red clicked? if yes set to red, if not, set to none. (you can do this in two line of code)

```
var bgColor = $('#green').is(':checked') ? 'green' : $('#red').is(':checked') ? 'red' : '';
 $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var bgColor = $('#green').is(':checked') ? 'green' : $('#red').is(':checked') ? 'red' : '';
    $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="news" value="right" id="right">Show News on the right</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="news" value="left" id="left">Show News on the left</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="color" name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">Set background color</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="green" id="green">Show green colors</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="red" id="red">Show red colors</label>
  <br>
</form>
<button>Customize!</button>
```

Comment: alright, but if both are checked, it has to be green. if none are checked - white, so its not going to work I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Check if this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/kxnqmjoy/) works for you.

You need to attach event handler to checkboxes to get it work. Please check the modified code below.

I have modified the code as per requirement. By this way you will get the desired output even if you add more checkboxes with different color and high priority will be given to green color.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name='color_scheme']").on("change", function() {

    if (this.checked && $("input[name='color_scheme']:checked").length == 1) {
        $('body').css('background-color', $(this).val());
    } else if ((this.checked && this.value === 'green') || $("input[name='color_scheme']:checked").length > 1) {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
    } else if (!this.checked && $("input[name='color_scheme']:checked").length == 1) {
        $('body').css('background-color', $("input[name='color_scheme']:checked").val());
    } else {
        $('body').css('background-color', '');
    }

});
});
```

Comment: almost. I need to be able to check two boxes and the green will have priority over red in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. But the issue will arise if both the checkbox is checked. So you should opt for radio button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // on button click,  get the selected checkbox by using name attribute
  $("#custom").click(function() {
    // get the value of the checkbox
    var checkedRadio = $('input[name="color_scheme"]:checked').val();
    // add the color
    $('body').css('background-color', checkedRadio);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="news" value="right" id="right">Show News on the right</label><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="news" value="left" id="left">Show News on the left</label><br>
  <label><input type="color" name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">Set background color</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="green" id="green">Show green colors</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="red" id="red">Show red colors</label><br>
</form>
<button id="custom">Customize!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var bg = 'white'; // default color is white
    if ($('#green').is(':checked')) { // if green is checked then show bg as green
      bg = 'green';
    } else if ($('#red').is(':checked')) { // else red
      bg = 'red';
    }
    $('body').css('background-color', bg);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="news" value="right" id="right">Show News on the right</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="news" value="left" id="left">Show News on the left</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="color" name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">Set background color</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="green" id="green">Show green colors</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="red" id="red">Show red colors</label>
  <br>
</form>
<button>Customize!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
I hope it will help you, because it may exactly match with your requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnCustomize").on("click", function(){
        if($('#green').prop('checked') == true){
            $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
        }else if($('#red').prop('checked') == true){
            $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        }else {
            $('body').css('background-color', '');
        }
    });
});
```

JsFiddle for the same
https://jsfiddle.net/69r5nmrw/2/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="news" value="right" id="right">Show News on the right</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="news" value="left" id="left">Show News on the left</label><br>
    <label><input type="color" name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">Set background color</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="green" id="green">Show green colors</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="color_scheme" value="red" id="red">Show red colors</label><br>
</form>
<button>Customize!</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    if($('#red').is(':checked')){
       if($('#green').is(':checked')){
          $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
       }else{
          $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
       }
    }else if($('#green').is(':checked')){
       $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
    }else{
       $('body').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the power of `CSS selectors` here. don't use `JS/jQuery` to manipulate the `CSS` as mush as you can, this makes your life easier. trust me.

**HTML**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-color="green">Green
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-color="red">Red
</label>
<p>
    <button type="button">Customize</button>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
body.red {
    background-color: red;
}

body[class*=green] {
    background-color: green;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('body').toggleClass($this.data('color'), $this.is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/ajpfhogm/)